# Can I use conditional formatting to format new additions to a table in excel?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a table in excel, the contents of which populate a drop-down list. Other users of the spreadsheet will be adding new items to the table. Because there are quite a lot of items in the table, I want to be able to see which items were in the original table and which have been added by other users. Is there a way to use conditional formatting so that new additions to the table can be coloured differently so I can immediately see what items have been added? Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to use conditional formatting to do this, you'd probably need to use VBA to log the changes. But there is a feature in Excel that allows you to track changes, see here: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Track-changes-in-a-shared-workbook-951bdf89-9ee6-4777-b31e-33ad0f594d18

Comment: Great, thanks very much, this will do the trick!

Comment: I have a quick idea, but could you clarify that when you say "table", do you mean an actual Formatted Table (where the headers/references are like `=Sum([header1],[@header2])...` (or whatever).  If *not*  and it's just a grouping of text/values, you could perhaps just make the info be filled in with a grey color. Then, when someone adds a row, it will by default be a white background.  But I agree with @BenShelton, and tracking changes is probably the way to go, as it's a bit more robust, definitive, and explanatory than a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but yes I do mean a properly formatted table. I tried changing the formatting of the surrounding cells that would become part of the table once values have been entered, but as soon as you click away and the table extends to include these values, the formatting automatically changes to that of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Excel CF does not 'remember' what was somewhere previously but perhaps it does not need to for your requirement, as having detected that rows have been added presumably you would want some way to reset to no formatting before further rows are added.

So, assuming your Table starts in Row1 enter the existing number of rows in the Table (including header) in say E1. Then select what you want to apply CF to (say ColumnsA:C), clear any exiting CF and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=AND(ROW()>$E$1,COUNTBLANK(A1:C1)<3)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select colouring of choice, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

'Reset' is by manually changing E1 to the value of the highest row number then in use by the Table.

This only looks for extra rows, so deleting an existing row from the Table before adding one new row will not trigger the CF.